# cURL "response reading failed" in FTPS file transfer

Tags: ftp, curl, ftps

I am trying to download a directory and it's files using cURL via FTPS.

The following command gets me very close - I successfully logged in and set the clear command channel, but then it fails with `curl: (56) response reading failed`

```
curl -v --ftp-ssl --data-ascii --ftp-pasv --no-epsv --user myusername:XXXXXXXX ftp://ftp.server.com:21 -Q "CCC"
* About to connect() to ftp.server.com port 21 (#0)*
Trying 55.55.55.55... connected
< 220-This System Is For Authorized Users Only.
< 220-
< 220 Secure FTP Server - SecureTransport ready.
> AUTH SSL
< 234 SSLv23/TLSv1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: DC=local; DC=ftp_host_company; DC=us; OU=Accounts; OU=SSL Accounts; CN=ftp.server.com
*        start date: 2012-02-14 16:29:37 GMT
*        expire date: 2015-02-14 16:59:37 GMT
*        common name: ftp.server.com (matched)
*        issuer: DC=local; DC=ftp_host_company; CN=Configuration; CN=Services; CN=Public Key Services;  CN=AIA; CN=FTP_hosting_company Issuing CA 1
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> USER myusername
< 331 Password required for myusername.
> PASS XXXXXXXX
< 230 Virtual user myusername logged in.
> PBSZ 0
< 200 PBSZ=0
> PROT P
< 200 PROT command successful
> PWD
< 257 "/" is current directory.
* Entry path is '/'
> CCC
< 200 command channel cleared.
> PASV
* Connect data stream passively
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* response reading failed
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
curl: (56) response reading failed
```

The ftps host specifically said that I would need to connect with FTPS with Clear Command
Channel on Port 21 - anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

CCC is used to downgrade the command channel back from SSL to plain text, that is after the successful response to CCC is received both sides must do a SSL_shutdown on the socket. Thus curl must deal with this inherent semantic of the command and it is not sufficient to let curl just send this command like it would do with any other arbitrary command. Instead you have to use the `--ftp-ssl-ccc` option.

Comment: adding the option --ftp-ssl-ccc

Comment: @Odelya: "adding the option --ftp-ssl-ccc" - does not work, gives en error messages, there is no such option ..... Please give a detailed error message if you want help. If you still keep adding just small fragments of the problem I will ignore future comments.